# Synonims extraction from wikidata via sparql

Tags: sparql, wikidata

i'm trying to extract lists of synonyms of chemical compounds, using the SPARQL query, however I'm not able to produce any working query. 
In particular I would like for each compound to get its name and the list of aliases ("also known as") for multiple languages.

I did not find any decent example out there, here what I could produce:

```
SELECT ?element ?elementLabel ?elementAltLabel ?alternative 
WHERE {
  ?element wdt:P31 wd:Q11344.
  OPTIONAL { ?subject skos:altLabel ?alternative . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,ja".} 
}
LIMIT 2
```

which unfortunately is going in timeout.

I tried to understand how this language is working but I've clearly done some big stupid mistakes here.

Comment: Maybe try `OPTIONAL { ?element skos:altLabel ?alternative . }` instead of your current `OPTIONAL... `.

Comment: That's correct. Inside the `OPTIONAL` you use `?subject` as variable while outside you have `?elements` - this is indeed a huge left-join and will timeout. Use the same variables. Don't copy and paste from somewhere without understanding it - that's what most likely happened here

Comment: Thanks! Yes I had no idea what I was doing...

Comment: unfortunately fixing that stupid mistake lead to this query:
`SELECT ?element ?elementLabel ?alternative
WHERE {
  ?element wdt:P31 wd:Q11344 .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".} 
  ?element skos:altLabel ?alternative . 
}
LIMIT 100`

which doesn't seems to correctly filter the languages (I get results in any) as I understood the SERVICE directive is supposed to do ... 

Moreover I could not find documentation about skos:Label ...

Comment: you misunderstand the label `SERVICE` . It's a magic Blazegraph triple store built-in and beyond standard SPARQL. That's why you can use `?elementLabel` without binding it to any variable in a triple pattern. On the other hand, `?alternative` is a standard SPARQL variable and not affected by the label SERVICE. That means, you have to use a proper SPARQL FILTER as anybody else has to do

Comment: `filter(langmatches(lang(?alternative), "en"))`